# Python Matrix Manipulation; using list comprehension and for loops

Tags: python

The question:
The objective is to create a 10x10 matrix (in native Python this would be a list of lists), where
every element has the value 42. You should do this three times: once using numpy, once using
list comprehension, and once using loops. After generating the matrix, multiply all elements on
the diagonal by 4. Divide all elements in the 7th row by 2. Add 17 to all elements in the 1st
and 3rd columns. Also find how many matrix elements are larger than 42. Note that you should
probably use a separate cell again to print the result, otherwise it will be printed 10000 times in
the timeit process

I was able to easily do this with numpy but am struggling to do it with loops and list comprehension. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Also read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/843953)
|
[Open letter to students with homework problems](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166/39188)
|
[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953)

Comment: what do you mean by "the diagonal"?

Answer (score -1):

List comprehension:

```
size = 10

# generate
my_list = [[42 for i in range(size)] for j in range(size)]

# multiply diagonal
my_list = [[my_list[row][col] * 4 if row == col else my_list[row][col] for row in range(size)] for col in range(size)]
# if you want the reverse diagonal, use this line as well
my_list = [[my_list[row][col] * 4 if row == size - col - 1 else my_list[row][col] for row in range(size)] for col in range(size)]

# divide 7th row
my_list[6] = [x >> 1 for x in my_list[6]] # shift right 1 is faster than divide by 2

# find count greater than 42 by flattening list and getting elements greater than 42
count = len([x for x in [val for row in my_list for val in row] if x > 42])

print(count)
```

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a forum to crowdsource your work. Please read [ask] and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Doing someone's homework / exercise for them doesn't help them in the slightest because programming is more than "find an answer on Stack Overflow", and it doesn't help the community because it only encourages more questions that show no effort on OP's part. Your answer doesn't even _explain_ what you do in those list comprehensions to help OP's understanding, so IMO it's a low-quality _"here's your code"_ answer that deserves that downvote.